# Show Call Progress Screen in Android

Tags: android

i want to show call_Progress_Screen for the onGoing calls.
In android sdk_versions<20 it can be done by using the function showCallScreen() but its not working in android lollipop onwards..Is there a way to show the call_Progress_Screen in lollipop devices also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This api works fine from Lollipop onwards.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#showInCallScreen(boolean)